# Horizontal Blinds Inside Mount for Windows

Tags: windows, blinds

I am getting Horizontal Blinds Inside Mount as seen below. My window height is 50 inches. When ordering, manufacturer added another 1 inch so it extends down below to 51 inches onto the wall.

1. Is that pretty typical for Blind manufacturers to add another inch so they droop-extend down more below the window for Horizontal inside mount?
2. Additionally, I am going to get one more blind for another 50inch window. This time, I will tell them its 51 inches, so it will add to 52 inches. I noticed it extending down keeps little more of the draft away, during winter cold months. Are there any negative effects of having it extend down little more besides slight appearance? Its a corded blind, so I can pull up and down anyway. Are there functionality issues, or any side effects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the blinds are inside mounts, they would only go as far down as the window sill. The extra inch won't make any difference and will insure that the bottom rail sits firmly on the sill. If your window sill extends out an inch or so from the wall, having the blinds go below the sill will look kind of bad because the blinds will stick out from the inside mount. I think the one extra inch will be all you'll need. I think the manufacturers add an inch as a safety net. no functional issues in doing what you want.

Comment: I agree on the 'safety net' factor. I have one blind that came out about 2mm short. Visually you can't tell unless you look really closely. No-one cares in winter when the windows are shut, but in summer it makes it more susceptible to clattering in a slight breeze through the open window.